# I'm trying to use Data Validation in Google Sheets to only accept a hex color – any help appreciated

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I think the title says it all.  I have a shared google sheet which I'd like to limit several columns to make sure the information is correctly added as a hexcode.

I've been searching and I just can't seem to find anything, but this code I found for EXCEL may be a starting point:

```
=AND(LEN(A2)<13,ISERROR(HEX2DEC(A2))=FALSE)
```

It does not seem to work for Sheets...

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I notice that the max length of a hex value that hex2dec will accept in Google Sheets is 10 digits - how long (or in what range) does your number need to be?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ISNUMBER(HEX2DEC(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "#(.*)")))*(LEN(A1)<8)
```

[image]